# Session duration 24 hours

Tags: php, session

I have a PHP legacy app, which performs a login in which some session variables are set. In a configuration file (i.e. included *config.php* file) I have these lines to try to set session  duration to 24 hours:

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', '1');
session_set_cookie_params(86400); //24 hours session
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400);
```

But the user is being logged out after, more or less, 2 hours of session.

What configuration could be overriding these values? Or maybe I'm missing some extra command to force session duration?

Comment: Did you remove the old session cookie?

Comment: What's the OS? On Debian, the session GC is not run by PHP, but cron. The script looks in php.ini for the lifetime setting, so overwriting it in a script might not work.

Comment: It's Debian, and yes, there is a setting `session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440` in `php.ini`. I thought `ini_set` had priority over `php.ini`, should I ask the admin to change `php.ini`?

Comment: This depends enterly on your php, `php-fpm` can setup variables that cannot be changed with ini_set later on (`php_admin_value`)